# How to find field annotations for a MethodSymbol?

Tags: scala, reflection

Suppose that have a found a set of methods for a Type:

```
case class X()

object A{
   @someannotation
   val x=X()
}

def toType[T](a:T)(implicit tag: TypeTag[T]): Type = tag.tpe

val typ = toType(A)

// Get the public methods that return an X
val intMethods = typ.members.collect{ case m: ru.MethodSymbol if 
   m.isGetter && m.isPublic && m.returnType <:< typeOf[X]  => m }
```

How would I efficiently find the corresponding annotations for each element of intMethods?

```
intMethods.head.annotations
```

is empty because there are two entries in typ.decls for x. One is the found method and the other is the non-method field that holds the annotations. I can search by matching on:

```
getAnnotations(intMethods.head.toTerm.name.toString.trim)

def getAnnotations( name: String) ={
  typ.decls.filter{ s=>s.name.toString.trim==name.trim && !s.isMethod}.flatMap(_.annotations)
}
```

but all that toStringing and trimming is extremely slow (the trim is required because, one of the decls contains a trailing space, and the other not). Is there a better way to directly lookup a corresponding class field from a MethodSymbol?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the backing field of a getter with the `accessed` method:

```
intMethods.head.accessed.annotations
```

---

From the [documentation](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/scala-reflect/index.html#scala.reflect.api.Symbols$MethodSymbolApi@accessed:Symbols.this.Symbol):

```
/** Backing field for an accessor method, NoSymbol for all other term symbols. */
abstract def accessed: Universe.Symbol
```